# Given we only want the first record, is it better to sort before select in linq query?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq

```
 var myVar = context.Sessions .Where(s => somesConditions)session.EquipmentId
                              .Select(s => s.StartDateTime)
                              .OrderBy(s => s)
                              .FirstOrDefault();
```

**In the above query, would it be better to sort before selecting?**

- Readability

  It doesn't make much difference.
- Performance

  Is one better than the other?

**Edit :** I know this example is flawed because query could be replaced by a simple Min(). Nevertheless, act like it isn't so.

Comment: Your edit has changed the question to something completely different from what it was.

Comment: After your last edit, you **cannot** select before sorting amymore. so the question is no sense

Comment: yes, I guess so.  Sorry. I might as well delete my question right?

Comment: @AXMIM Do you want to know the answer to the original question? Then you might revert the last edit.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan to me

Comment: @dasblinkenlight well if there is value for community, why not. But I'm worried that I was just doing something completely wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you send this to an RDBMS through EF, there is no difference, because your RDBMS will pick the execution plan that it prefers, and ship a single result back to you. Moving projection ahead or behind the ordering step will make no difference.

The situation with in-memory LINQ is not the same: although there is hardly any difference when `Select` projects an existing value or an existing object from a collection of reference objects, this is not always the case.

Specifically, things would be different if you were to start with a collection of very large `struct`s. In this case you would be better off projecting a small field with `Select` before sorting to get better performance.

The situation would also change if you were projecting into a new object, because doing so would create temporary objects that need to be garbage-collected promptly after the sort.

Note that delaying the projection until after the call of `FirstOrDefault` would let you produce a nullable object from a non-nullable attribute:

```
var myVar = context.Sessions .Where(s => somesConditions)
    .OrderBy(s => s.StartDateTime)
    .FirstOrDefault()
    ?.Select(s => s.StartDateTime);
```

Assuming that `StartDateTime` is a `DateTime`, this query would produce a nullable `DateTime?` as the result, not a `DateTime` with the default value.

Comment: You nailed it. Specially with the projection explanation at the end.

Comment: Compiler doesn't like the "?" in the query. It is c++, what is the equivalent in c#?

Comment: @AXMIM It's C# 6 syntax. It works on .NET 4.5 and up.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the whole query will be translated to a SQL query and the work will be done by a SQL server. The query generated by the EF will be the same for both options, so the order of statements doesn't matter.